# Filter Date from current quarter

Tags: excel, vba

I need to filter Data with Date ONLY from Current Quarter onward, excluding all data with previous Quarter and year.........

```
Sub DateFilter() 
    Sheets("Base Sheet").Range("A1:CS1").AutoFilter Field:=36, _
        Criteria1:="<" & ThisQuarter 
End Sub
```

Comment: ...and do you have a question?

Comment: The above script doesn't work. I even tried with - Sub DateFilter()
Sheets("Base Sheet").Range("A1:CS1").AutoFilter Field:=36, Criteria1:="<=" & Application.EoQuarter(Date, -1)
End Sub

Comment: What is `EoQuarter`?  You can't make up functions and expect them to work.  Have you tried Googling your issue?  [so] isn't a "free code writing service"...

Comment: Something similar to  "EoMonth(Date, 0)" 'marks the last day of current month'

Comment: A good place to start would be a Google Search for "how to calculate end of quarter in vba"

Comment: Thank you for your assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The first result](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/54333-calculate-next-quarter-end-date-vba.html) from a [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=calculate%20end%20of%20quarter%20in%20excel%20vba) for "calculate end of quarter in excel vba" lead me to this answer:

```
DateSerial(Year(Range("B5")), Month(Range("B5")) + 4, 0)
```

which you can change to use today's date for the end of the current quarter like this:

```
DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) + 4, 0)
```

Another search for your question could be "autofilter current quarter excel".

Google should always be the first place to look for a solution to *any* problem.

Answer (score 2):

There is a parameter to filter for the current quarter: `xlFilterThisQuarter`

```
.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=xlFilterThisQuarter, Operator:=xlFilterDynamic
```

See the documentation:

- [Range.Autofilter Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-autofilter-method-excel)
- [XlAutoFilterOperator Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/xlautofilteroperator-enumeration-excel)
- [XlDynamicFilterCriteria enumeration](http://%20https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xldynamicfiltercriteria.aspx)

Comment: Yes i understand but need to filter excluding 'thisQuarter' "<"

Comment: @ChandrasekarR Well, then you should be much more clear in your question which says the opposite: *"I need to filter Data with Date ONLY from Current Quarter onward, excluding all data with previous Quarter and year"*

Comment: @ChandrasekarR - check out the [help/on-topic] as well as "[ask]" as well as "[mcve]".  Also see the [Stack Overflow Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) for more tips about posting questions, as well as **["How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)**. (+1)